# FirePro W4100 video card drive won't drive a displayport monitor at full resolution

Tags: windows-10, displayport, amd-graphics-card

I have an AMD FirePro W4100 card and it has 4 displayport outputs on the back.  I have discovered an infuriating limitation which is that it won't seem to drive my Dell UltraSharp U2713HM 27" monitor at its native 2560x1440 WQHD resolution.  I get this message instead:

[image]

Previous generation video cards with DVI outputs had no problem driving this monitor. This monitor has displayport and DVI inputs.  The monitor has on screen controls but no settings about displayport settings or modes.  On the AMD Control Center app I see the following:

[image]

The specs for the monitor state that it supports DisplayPort 1.2.

The video card is a display-port-output-only card with 4 displayport connectors.

Even when only one monitor is attached, I can not select 2560x1440 resolution in windows 10, and the warning above is shown.

My theories are:

- This is an early model displayport-enabled display and there's something wrong with the displayport support, it doesn't support the same displayport version that the FirePro W4100 supports.
- All the display port cables I can buy in a computer store are sub-standard.
- There's some configuration or something that I need to change to make displayport work, because this is a PC, and accidental complexity and horrendous piles of vendor-driven BS are required, unlike, say if this was a Mac.

The message when the thing is attached is shown here, and I can not figure it out. It appears to be written in a language that looks like English but makes no sense. Even when this is the ONLY display attached to this video card, the native 2560x1440 WQHD option is not enabled in Windows.   The messages seem to be talking about displayport display sharing:

The help button links to a completely useless page of nonsense about how if you have an HDMI monitor you should use an HDMI cable, and other banal and pointless noise.

The noise is shown here because people might want to verify for themselves that AMD doesn't know how to make help buttons link to actual help about DisplayPort displays and video cards not really working:

```
Digital Flat-Panels (DisplayPort Monitors)



The My Digital Flat-Panelsgroup becomes available in Standard View and Advanced View if you are using a digital display (such as a monitor or digital TV) that is connected through a DVI, DisplayPort, or HDMI™ connection.

A DisplayPort connection carries both digital and audio signal suitable for connecting to a home-theatre system. Use the various pages in the group to control how images appear on your display. Each page contains settings for configuring different display properties, such as improving image quality, performing color correction adjustments, and adding support for additional HDTV modes. 

For graphics cards that support the DisplayPort v1.2 standard, you can connect multiple DisplayPort displays to a single DisplayPort connection as long as the displays are compatible with the standard. Displays can be connected to a hub or using a daisy chain configuration. This type of multi-display capability is made possible through the multi-stream transport feature in the DisplayPort v1.2 standard. To determine the number of displays that can be connected to your card, see DisplayPort Diagnostic Information. For more information on the DisplayPort digital display interface and standard, see http://www.displayport.org.

DisplayPort Connectivity

If your digital flat-panel and graphics card are both equipped with DisplayPort connections, you can connect the panel to your computer using a single DisplayPort cable. This cable supplies video to your digital panel. To obtain audio, a separate connection must be made from the audio output of your computer to the audio input of your digital panel.

Note:You may first need to configure your digital panel for external audio. For more information see, the documentation for your panel.

It is also possible to connect a digital flat panel to a computer if the digital panel is equipped with an HDMI or DVI input. To do this, an HDMI or DVI cable and a DisplayPort-to-HDMI or DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter is required to obtain HDMI/DVI output from the DisplayPort connection on your graphics card. For HDMI, no additional connections are required for audio. For a list of AMD-recommended DisplayPort adapters and dongles, visit http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx. 


Digital Flat-Panel Properties (DisplayPort Monitors)

Display Color for Digital Flat-Panels (DisplayPort Monitors)

HDTV Support for Digital Flat-Panels (DisplayPort Monitors)
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a common problem with **low quality displayport cables**.  Oddly enough I still get this message even when I change to other displayport cables, but although I am getting warned, suddenly the full WQHD native resolution has become an available option for me to select in the Windows display settings.